# Arctan of $\frac{1}{0}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I applied the formula $\rho=\sqrt{z^2+r^2},\ \  \theta=\theta , \ \ \phi=\arctan \left (\frac{r}{z}\right )$ for the point in cylindrical coordinates $\left (1, -\frac{\pi}{6}, 0\right )$.

To calculate $\phi$ do we write it as followed?? $$\phi=\arctan \left (\frac{1}{0}\right )$$
Or is there an other way to write it??

Do we say: "Since it $\frac{1}{0}$ is not defined and we know that $\tan $ is not defined at $\frac{\pi}{2}$, we conclude that $\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}$." ??

Is the formulation correct?? Could I improve something??

Comment: The formula is correct when $z\neq 0$. For $z=0$, the point lies in the $xy$-plane. What is the altitude ($\phi$) of a point that lies in the plane?

Comment: $\phi $ is then the angle between the $xy-$plane and then $z-$axis, $\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Is this correct?? @WilliamStagner

Comment: Sorry, I just reread your question, and your formula is incorrect. It should be $\phi = \mathrm{arctan}(z/r)$.

Comment: We have $$r= \rho \sin \phi \\ z=\rho \cos \phi$$ 

Dividing these two relations, we get $$\frac{r}{z}=\frac{\sin \theta }{\cos \theta}=\tan \theta \Rightarrow \theta =\arctan \left (\frac{r}{z}\right )$$ Isn't it like that?? @WilliamStagner

Comment: It should be $r = \rho \sin \phi$ and $z = \rho \sin \phi$.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, $\arctan(1/0)$ isn't well-defined; it would be more accurate to write $\arctan(1/0^+)$ and $\arctan(1/0^-)$, as appropriate. This indicates that we consider the limits of $\arctan(1/x)$ as $x$ tends to zero. The one-sided limits are different: $\pi/2$ vs $-\pi/2$.

A bigger issue with the formula $\phi=\arctan \left (\frac{r}{z}\right) $ is that for negative   $z$ it gives negative values of $\phi$. But this is not what you want: $\phi$ normally ranges from $0$ to $\pi$ in spherical coordinates.

A similar issue already comes in two-dimensional geometry, where the polar angle $\theta$ satisfies $\theta = \arctan(y/x)$... except for all the cases when it doesn't. 
In programming this is solved by using the two-variable function `atan2` which takes $x$ and $y$ values, and returns polar angle. In mathematics,  we have to be aware that "take arctangent of ratio of coordinates" is not a universal recipe, and use other trigonometric   functions when appropriate.

In particular, knowing that $z=\rho\cos\phi$ in spherical coordinates tells that $z=0$ if and only if $\phi=\pi/2$. (With the exception of the origin $(0,0,0)$, where the angles are not defined.)